# Android Intent for Battery Saver Mode (Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop, tasker, battery-saver

I'm trying to setup a profile in tasker to automatically trigger the battery saver mode in Android 5.0. But all I found was an intent to launch the battery saver activity, but none to actually toggle it.

```
com.android.settings.Settings$BatterySaverSettingsActivity
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you find the answer for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Tasker it can be done by using the Run Shell Action you put `settings put global low_power 1` under the command box and be sure to check the box that says use root. Change the 1 to a 0 in order to turn off battery saver mode. So I'd hypothesize that it would be `com.android.settings.low_power` or something similar.

Comment: Answer should be programmatic. Your answer is based on the app itself running in Android.